# grub bootloader isn't loading

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, bootloader

I need some help with grub bootloader.
I have ubuntu installed and Windows 10, Grub used to load automatically but I messed some partitions and now it is not (automatically boots into windows). I have booted from flash and I can see my files are there [partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23ygT.png), the 457Gb is the ubuntu and the 230Gb is the windows (not sure what the third one is from image). Anyway I would like to restore grub (so I can manually choose which OS to load). I tried

```
fdisk -l
sudo update-grub
```

but got this error `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of`/cow'.`
[terminal ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVXAS.png), I really hope there is a solution for this withot me losing the data (specially the data on ubuntu)

Comment: i suggest to try first # sudo grub-install --recheck , # sudo grub-install /dev/sdX , if the commands complete without any error try to run # sudo update-grub , if it still not work and you receive the error message , boot to linux os from falsh usb , then mount the drives, chroot to system then mount  , /dev , /proc , /sys , /pts , connect the internet copy the resolv.conf using -L option to to be able internet inside chroot system the reinstall agaien grub2 grub-pc and grub-common  GOODLUCK .

Comment: The /cow means you are trying to update the live installer not your install. Answer below using Boot-Repair is often easier, but you can mount your install partitions and install grub or do a full chroot into install and run updates & repairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifted from the community wiki:

1. Insert your Ubuntu CD, reboot your computer and set it to boot from CD in the BIOS and boot into a live session. You can also use a LiveUSB if you have created one in the past.
2. Install and run Boot-Repair.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

3. Click "Recommended Repair".
4. Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear.

Alternatively download the boot-repair-disk.iso, make a bootable cd or usb key from this and boot it to perform the repair

[boot repair disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)