# Ubuntu 22.04 not loading after installing it on dual boot with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 22.04, hp

Trying to setup dual boot ubuntu on a HP notebook, and currently only windows 10 is booting (default, pre-installed with the notebook). Followed the default next-next-next-finish installation by using a UBS stick, and the only thing that I changed was the allocated space for windows and for ubuntu: asked to be 50% for each OS. Then after the intallation is done, there is no way to select Ubuntu or Windows, it just boot straight up to windows. The closest way to achieve something, was hitting ESC before the boot, which leads me to the image below

[image]

and after that, hit F9 and selected the first Ubuntu option from the image below

[image]

which lead me to this screen instead of booting to Ubuntu:

[image]

What exactly is going on? How can I fix this? Should I go for something like boot-repair, as suggested here https://askubuntu.com/a/1185889 ? Or try to reinstall Ubuntu 22.04 on top of the existing installation?
Weirdly enough, I noticed every time I try to boot ubuntu, it is added as a new option/entry to the list.

Comment: First thing to do is type *ls*. Can you post by way of comment what is displayed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: I'll check it out as soon as I can. Unfortunately couldn't bring the computer for new year's travel, so will only be able to check it out on Jan 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

1. Go to BIOS setting.
2. Set Ubuntu on 1st position.
3. Save and exit
   I think this method will work for you.

And if still not work. Try to Reinstall Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

In bios settings, change boot priority and place ubuntu on top, then u will get grub menu upon boot everytime where u can choose between windows and ubuntu.